# SonarQube: ruleset doesn't respect PSR

Tags: php, sonarqube

I have a little issue with SonarQube to scan PHP code.

When scanning the work, there is an error coming a hundred times:

> Move this open curly brace to the end of the previous line

This apply on this code for example:

```
class Edit extends Container
{
```

It shouldn't as PSR are clear on this topic :

> 1. Opening braces for classes MUST go on the next line, and closing
>      braces MUST go on the next line after the body.
> 2. Opening braces for
>      methods MUST go on the next line, and closing braces MUST go on the
>      next line after the body.
> 3. Opening braces for control structures MUST
>      go on the same line, and closing braces MUST go on the next line after
>      the body

When I look in the detail of the error in Sonar, this is what the rule seems to follow, which is not appropriate:

> Sharing some coding conventions is a key point to make it possible for a team to efficiently collaborate. This rule make it mandatory to place open curly braces at the end of lines of code.
>
> And there it shows me the example of the if condition

```
if(...) {
 //...
}
```

Any idea to follow the proper rule?

Comment: How about to ignore this errors. Only thing to decide here: Do it like `SonarQube` or like `PSR` does!? Maybe you can deactivate the special check in `SonarQube`

Comment: What Quality Profile are you using for this analysis?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found a solution:

- edit your project configuration by disabling the faulty rules and enabling the wanted ones, in this case: PSR2. You can also add some additionnal rules, for example in my case, the Magento 2 ones ;
- to make the changes taken in to account: launch a new build.

Hope it will help other.